# Error C2679 using a custom extraction operator

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I have a custom type, currently placeheld by a std::pair. (It will have more data on it before I'm through...) and am reading it in from a file.

I have cut my code down to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

// Show duration isn't an issue, so I can treat all times as integers in the range 0-2400.
using Time = uint16_t;
using Show = pair<Time,Time>; // Placeholder type, for now. This will probably end up as some sort of a std::tuple.

// Build a Show object from its component pieces.
inline Show make_show(Time start, Time finish)
{
    return make_pair(start, finish);
}

inline Time& start(Show& show)
{
    return show.first;
}

inline Time& finish(Show& show)
{
    return show.second;
}

// Get a Show object from a stream.
inline istream& operator>>(istream& is, Show& show)
{
    is >> start(show) >> finish(show);
    return is;
}

// Get a vector (sorted by start time) of all the shows in an EOF terminated stream
vector<Show> readShows(istream& stream)
{
    auto result = vector<Show>{};
    // main.cpp, line 58 is the next line.
    copy(istream_iterator<Show>(stream), istream_iterator<Show>(), back_inserter(result));
    sort(begin(result), end(result));
    return result;
}
```

However, when I compile this I get an error. In essence the error is complaining that when it tries to create an `istream_iterator<Show>` object it cannot find a suitable `operator>>`: "`error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Show' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`".

This is confusing me, since I *do* have a function with the signature `istream& operator>>(istream& is, Show& show)` declared higher up in the program.

This error can be reproduced by compiling with the default Windows compiler in Visual Studio 2013, or by compiling under Clang (which gives "`error : invalid operands to binary expression ('istream_type' (aka 'basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >') and 'std::pair<Time, Time>')`" - basically the same error with different wording.)

Any help would be welcome.

The full error is given here:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ScratchSpace, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(256): error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Show' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(485): could be 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(void *&)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(448): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(long double &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(430): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(double &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(float &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(392): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned __int64 &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(373): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(__int64 &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(353): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned long &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(335): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(long &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(317): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned int &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(291): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(int &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(272): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned short &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(237): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(short &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(218): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::_Bool &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(211): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(204): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(198): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1103): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><char,std::char_traits<char>,_Ty>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &&,_Ty &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Show
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1093): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1086): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char *)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1079): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1072): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char *)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, Show)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(255) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::istream_iterator<Show,char,std::char_traits<char>,ptrdiff_t>::_Getval(void)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\iterator(222) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::istream_iterator<Show,char,std::char_traits<char>,ptrdiff_t>::_Getval(void)' being compiled
1>          c:\users\gbenglisha\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\scratchspace\scratchspace\main.cpp(58) : see reference to class template instantiation       'std::istream_iterator<Show,char,std::char_traits<char>,ptrdiff_t>' being compiled
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Side note: std::pair is quite useless here, you should make a `struct Show { Time start, Time finish };`

Comment: @DieterLücking Well, that does actually fix the error (and it compiles once I return `main()` and `operator<(Show...)` to the source code). But do you (or anyone else) know why? Thanks muchly,

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl#Notes `Name lookup rules make it impractical to declare operators in global or user-defined namespace that operate on types from the std namespace`  with more detail in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#Lookup_rules

Comment: @Cubbi Thanks! That was really useful. Any chance you could copy that comment into an actual answer, so I can give you credit for the solution?

Comment: There's been a lot of duplicates of this question on SO, although they are hard to search for since it's a different overloaded operator each time. I'll pick one that was already used to mark other questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ADL lookup is failing you in this case. You are relying on ADL lookup to find your overload for `istream` and `pair` (which is not in namespace std::), and it can not be found. Likely has to do with `istream_iterator` templates (not saying much, I know!). It all works well when using `stream >> show;` instead of istream_iterator algorithm - so you probably can do a simple loop if you are not fixed on using iterator + copy.

One dreaded way of fixing it would be to define `operator >>` in namespace `std`, but this technique is frowned upon for a good reason. There should be other way to help ADL here, but I am not sure how to do this.